# Bootstrap tooltips and popover for JS dynamic entries

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popover

Bootstrap 3 *tooltips* and *popovers* work perfectly within html code, but it seems it does not apply to dynamically built entries. For example :

```
urlline += '<a href="' + this + '" target="_blank" ';
urlline += 'data-content="' + ircline + '" ';
urlline += 'data-placement="bottom" ';
urlline += 'data-container="body" ';
urlline += 'data-toggle="popover">';
urlline += this + '</a>';
```

In that scenario, a `hover` on the created links won't show any `popover`. Same result with `tooltips`.
I have `popover` initialized with `$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({trigger: 'hover'});` and it works for existing *HTML*, just not for dynamically created entries.

I'm no JS expert so I might be missing something, any hint?

Answer (score 0):

Are you inserting urlline into DOM using jQuery, something like this `$('#somelementID').html(urlline);` ?
If yes, then initialize bootstrap popover/tooltip after inserting that element into DOM using jquery, using `$('a#id').popover({trigger: 'hover'});`

Comment: Already did that, unfortunately it does not change anything, added an _id_ to the _a_ component then `$('#a-' + urldate).popover({trigger: 'hover'});`, still no popover...

Comment: It seems like it's all about the page not being ready yet. I added a setInterval() function and have a popover() inside it, turns out when the time's up, the popovers occur. I'll dig this and post the results.

Comment: So it seems it was a matter of waiting till the elements are fully loaded, this small piece of code did the trick:

    $.ajaxSetup({
        async: false
    });

All the elements fetched by `getJSON` are then fetched synchronously and there's no race condition anymore.

Answer (score 0):

try use a function in js with the popover's properties even in your content you can use a ajax o put a html code or finally parameters as you prefer (this work for me in datatable):

```
function popovers(object, title, content, placement){
    $(objet).popover({
      html:true, 
      title: title,
      content: content,
      placement: placement
})
}
```